# VBA: if-else-statement run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)'

Tags: excel, vba, data-entry

I've encountered an error relating to MS Excel VBA in developing a data entry form.

Following is my data entry form/userform:-

[Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu47w.png)

Now, what I am trying to do is to:-

1- To have 1x PI No. and all left side details (type,product type,sub-product type, product code, customer & brand)

2- Duplicate all left side details with each entered sizes (order & packed)
**may refer to red highlighted illustration in userform picture*

After I did the codes as below:-

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim iRow As Long
Dim j As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PKG_Database")

iRow = [Counta(PKG_Database!A:A)] + 1

If PKGform.PKGText_prodcode.Value = "" Or PKGform.PKGText_prodcode.Value = 0 Then

MsgBox ("You did not enter the details")
 
Else
        
    If PKGform.PKGTxt_XSorder = "" Or PKGform.PKGTxt_XSorder = 0 Then
        
        Else
        With sh
        
        .Cells(iRow, 1) = [Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]
        .Cells(iRow, 2) = PKGform.PKGText_PI.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 3) = PKGform.PKGText_prodtype
        .Cells(iRow, 4) = PKGform.PKGText_subprodtype
        .Cells(iRow, 5) = PKGform.PKGText_prodcode
        .Cells(iRow, 6) = PKGform.PKGText_customer
        .Cells(iRow, 7) = PKGform.PKGText_brand
        .Cells(iRow, 8) = "XS"
        .Cells(iRow, 9) = PKGform.PKGTxt_XSorder
        .Cells(iRow, 10) = PKGform.PKGTxt_XSpacked
        .Cells(iRow, 12) = Application.UserName
        iRow = iRow + 1
        
        End With
        End If
        
            
            If PKGform.PKGTxt_Sorder = "" Or PKGform.PKGTxt_Sorder = 0 Then
            
            Else
            With sh
            
            .Cells(iRow, 1) = [Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]
            .Cells(iRow, 2) = PKGform.PKGText_PI.Value
            .Cells(iRow, 3) = PKGform.PKGText_prodtype
            .Cells(iRow, 4) = PKGform.PKGText_subprodtype
            .Cells(iRow, 5) = PKGform.PKGText_prodcode
            .Cells(iRow, 6) = PKGform.PKGText_customer
            .Cells(iRow, 7) = PKGform.PKGText_brand
            .Cells(iRow, 8) = "S"
            .Cells(iRow, 9) = PKGform.PKGTxt_Sorder
            .Cells(iRow, 10) = PKGform.PKGTxt_Spacked
            .Cells(iRow, 12) = Application.UserName
            iRow = iRow + 1
            
            End With
            End If
            
            
                If PKGform.PKGTxt_Morder = "" Or PKGform.PKGTxt_Morder = 0 Then
                
                Else
                With sh
                
                .Cells(iRow, 1) = [Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]
                .Cells(iRow, 2) = PKGform.PKGText_PI.Value
                .Cells(iRow, 3) = PKGform.PKGText_prodtype
                .Cells(iRow, 4) = PKGform.PKGText_subprodtype
                .Cells(iRow, 5) = PKGform.PKGText_prodcode
                .Cells(iRow, 6) = PKGform.PKGText_customer
                .Cells(iRow, 7) = PKGform.PKGText_brand
                .Cells(iRow, 8) = "M"
                .Cells(iRow, 9) = PKGform.PKGTxt_Morder
                .Cells(iRow, 10) = PKGform.PKGTxt_Mpacked
                .Cells(iRow, 12) = Application.UserName
                iRow = iRow + 1
                
                End With
                End If
                
                        If PKGform.PKGTxt_Lorder = "" Or PKGform.PKGTxt_Lorder = 0 Then
                    
                        Else
                        With sh
                        
                        .Cells(iRow, 1) = [Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]
                        .Cells(iRow, 2) = PKGform.PKGText_PI.Value
                        .Cells(iRow, 3) = PKGform.PKGText_prodtype
                        .Cells(iRow, 4) = PKGform.PKGText_subprodtype
                        .Cells(iRow, 5) = PKGform.PKGText_prodcode
                        .Cells(iRow, 6) = PKGform.PKGText_customer
                        .Cells(iRow, 7) = PKGform.PKGText_brand
                        .Cells(iRow, 8) = "L"
                        .Cells(iRow, 9) = PKGform.PKGTxt_Lorder
                        .Cells(iRow, 10) = PKGform.PKGTxt_Lpacked
                        .Cells(iRow, 12) = Application.UserName
                        iRow = iRow + 1
                        
                        End With
                        End If
                        
                            If PKGform.PKGTxt_XLorder = "" Or PKGform.PKGTxt_XLorder = 0 Then
                            
                            Else
                            With sh
                            
                            .Cells(iRow, 1) = [Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]
                            .Cells(iRow, 2) = PKGform.PKGText_PI.Value
                            .Cells(iRow, 3) = PKGform.PKGText_prodtype
                            .Cells(iRow, 4) = PKGform.PKGText_subprodtype
                            .Cells(iRow, 5) = PKGform.PKGText_prodcode
                            .Cells(iRow, 6) = PKGform.PKGText_customer
                            .Cells(iRow, 7) = PKGform.PKGText_brand
                            .Cells(iRow, 8) = "XL"
                            .Cells(iRow, 9) = PKGform.PKGTxt_XLorder
                            .Cells(iRow, 10) = PKGform.PKGTxt_XLpacked
                            .Cells(iRow, 12) = Application.UserName
                            iRow = iRow + 1
                            
                            End With
                            End If
                            
                                If PKGform.PKGTxt_XXLorder = "" Or PKGform.PKGTxt_XXLorder = 0 Then
                
                                Else
                                With sh
                                
                                .Cells(iRow, 1) = [Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]
                                .Cells(iRow, 2) = PKGform.PKGText_PI.Value
                                .Cells(iRow, 3) = PKGform.PKGText_prodtype
                                .Cells(iRow, 4) = PKGform.PKGText_subprodtype
                                .Cells(iRow, 5) = PKGform.PKGText_prodcode
                                .Cells(iRow, 6) = PKGform.PKGText_customer
                                .Cells(iRow, 7) = PKGform.PKGText_brand
                                .Cells(iRow, 8) = "XXL"
                                .Cells(iRow, 9) = PKGform.PKGTxt_XXLorder
                                .Cells(iRow, 10) = PKGform.PKGTxt_XXLpacked
                                .Cells(iRow, 12) = Application.UserName
                                iRow = iRow + 1
                                
                                End With
                                End If
                                
                                    If PKGform.PKGTxt_XXXLorder = "" Or PKGform.PKGTxt_XXXLorder = 0 Then
                
                                    Else
                                    With sh
                                    
                                    .Cells(iRow, 1) = [Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]
                                    .Cells(iRow, 2) = PKGform.PKGText_PI.Value
                                    .Cells(iRow, 3) = PKGform.PKGText_prodtype
                                    .Cells(iRow, 4) = PKGform.PKGText_subprodtype
                                    .Cells(iRow, 5) = PKGform.PKGText_prodcode
                                    .Cells(iRow, 6) = PKGform.PKGText_customer
                                    .Cells(iRow, 7) = PKGform.PKGText_brand
                                    .Cells(iRow, 8) = "XXXL"
                                    .Cells(iRow, 9) = PKGform.PKGTxt_XXXLorder
                                    .Cells(iRow, 10) = PKGform.PKGTxt_XXXLpacked
                                    .Cells(iRow, 12) = Application.UserName
                                    iRow = iRow + 1
                                    
                                    End With
                                    End If
                    

End If
```

Let say, I enter numbers (order & packed) in userform for XS & S size, The details for XS (earlier codes) are perfectly captured into the table. But It appears a run-time error for S (later codes):-
[run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEs4Y.png)

In general, this codes only able to capture 1 size at one time only. If exceed 2 and more sizes, it will only capture data for whichever earlier in the codes then the run time error will be appeared for the next codes after the if else ends statement for earlier size (XS size for example).

I really don't know what causes the error.

You may get the files from this link:-
[Excel File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArsYUDAPDSpRjUL0DC1bJnaKcrLT?e=R2779g)

**Pls find macro named "Submit2" to see the codes. Macro named "show_form" to execute the userform.

May someone help me on this issue ? Thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: You are relying on default members and something goes awry. Try to be more explicit, for example `.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = PKGform.PKGText_subprodtype.Value`

Comment: What line produces the error?

Comment: `.Cells(iRow, 1) = [Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]` starting from this line

Comment: @JohnAlexiou may you deliberate more on the first comment. Fyi, my vba skill was very low. thank you for helping

Comment: Why are you assigning text that looks like a date to worksheet cells? Dates should be numeric and then can be made to have any format you like with Number Formatting. This expression evaluates to text... not a number: `[Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]`

Comment: Don't use parentheses here: `MsgBox ("You did not enter the details")` It's redundant and causes the VBA virtual machine to create a temporary string as a copy of the string literal between the quotation marks. Do this instead: `MsgBox "You did not enter the details"`

Comment: `If PKGform.PKGTxt_XSorder = "" Or PKGform.PKGTxt_XSorder = 0 Then` can be replaced by the more efficient, shorter, and easier to read and reason about: `If Not PKGform.PKGTxt_XSorder Then`

Comment: But your central problem can be fixed by changing the lines throwing errors to this pattern: `.Cells(iRow, 1) = Now`

Comment: @HafizziHairi - The `.Cells()` method returns a `Range` object and you are assigning it to a value, but taking advantage of the default property of `Range` cells. The same when you read the contents of a text box. Whenever applicable add the `.Value` in the end to make is it is clear you are writing to the value of cell and not assigning a new `Range` object.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: untested code below*

The issue the use of square brackets which evaluates the contents. It is superfluous at best, and might be the source of the error here. Try the following instead.

```
.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Format(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

to store a text value of formatted date, or

```
.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Now()
.Cells(iRow, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
```

to store the date and format it the way you want.

Comment: Evaluate() does not expect a cell address inside.

Comment: @ExcelHero when you do `[A1]` it translates to `Range("A1")`, not `Evaluate("A1")` right?

Comment: @JohnAlexiou No. `[a1]` evaluates to the same Range object that `Range("a1")` evaluates to. It doesn't translate. But the reason that `[a1]` evaluates to that object is because `A1` is a reference to a worksheet range. The square brackets are just a shorthand for the Evaluate() function where the argument is ONE string literal. But the Evaluate() function, similar to the evaluation that takes place for a formula in a worksheet cell, is not limited to ranges. `="abc"` in a cell would evaluate to the string, `abc` In exactly the same way ["abc"] will evaluate to `abc`. No range is returned!

Comment: @JohnAlexiou continued... In a similar fashion `[Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]` legitimately evaluates to a string representation of today's date. There is nothing wrong with that other than it's not a great idea to enter TEXT as a representation of a date into a worksheet cell. But assigning a string to a Range object's `.Value` property will not cause an error and is often desired. The problem that the OP is facing is that `.Value` is not being reached.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou The bulk of your answer is sensible, but the first sentence and the first code example are just plain wrong. You need to delete them or this answer gets a down-vote.

Comment: My code is working perfectly for the first line but fails in the second line (duplication part). For example, I entered 2 sizes; XS & S. For XS (code is written earlier), it works fine and able to captured all the data. But for S (code is written after), it appeared to have run-time error for each statement within the code.

Comment: Not only `.Cells(iRow, 1) = [Text(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY")]`, but following statement as well >> `.Cells(iRow, 2) = PKGform.PKGText_PI.Value` and so on...

Comment: I also replaced the code with 
`sh.Cells(iRow,1).Resize(1,10).Value = Array( _
    Format(Now(),"DD/MM/YYYY"), _
    PKGform.PKGText_PI.Value, _
    PKGform.PKGText_prodtype.Value, _
    PKGform.PKGText_subprodtype.Value, _
    PKGform.PKGText_prodcode.Value, _
    PKGform.PKGText_customer.Value, _
    PKGform.PKGText_brand.Value, _
    "XXXL", _
    PKGform.PKGTxt_XXXLorder.Value )

sh.Cells(iRow, 12).Value = Application.UserName
iRow = iRow + 1 `

the error still appear when it goes for the S (later codings) part (same example with XS & S as above)

Comment: @HafizziHairi You need to do the lines like this: `.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = PKGform.PKGText_PI.Value`

Comment: @HafizziHairi Please update your question above. Point out where the error happens in the question and also show the value you are attempting to assign to a cell when the error happens. As it stands now, there is way too much noise in your question and your code. Hone in on the error.

Comment: the error still pop-up. In general, after it execute and get the data from userform and copy into the worksheet (XS details). The error start to popup from S size statement to XXXL statement. The duplication of the entered details part still got error.